# How to test with Espresso if the popup of an AutoCompleteTextView is open or not in my Android activity

Tags: android, android-espresso, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView in my Android Activity

In my espresso test, I want to check if the popup with the proposals is opened or closed.

How can I do that?

I have tried many ideas, including:

```
onData(anything()).inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup()).check(doesNotExist());
onData(anything()).inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
onData(anything()).atPosition(0).inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

In these particular cases, the test just fails or goes to an infinite loop

Example:

In my Adapter, I have 2 values: "abc" and "def"

- when I enter "d", the popup shall open with "def"
- Then if I add "g", the popup shall close

How can I test (within an Espresso test) if the popup is closed?